# Как сделать listbox или drop-down-menu в плагине для adobe premiere?

Tags: c++, api, visual-studio-2015, плагин, adobe

Перечитал документацию для adobe premiere но не нашёл как это сделать.

Плагин(видео эфектов) или видео фильтров.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя официальныи примеры c adobe after-efects(которые можно скачать вместе с документацией) в нескольких примерах там приветствует многофункциональный list-box